# Use define without factory

Tags: ruby, include, factory-bot

Here is a working code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address, class: 'Address' do |a|
    #...
  end
end
```

I want to call the method `define` without `factoryGirl`.

I tried this:

```
include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

define do
  factory :address, class: 'Address' do |a|
    #...
  end
end
```

and I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `define' for main:Object
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including [the proper module](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/8a65569f102ac2593e7c73bd029d5072e4641af8/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb) will make it work (the one, where `define` is defined):

```
include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Default
```